# UNION ALL query using WITH statement breaks

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote a query using with statement and union all. But, I am not used to writing complex queries. It keeps breaking in the union all. Please point me where it is wrong?

```
WITH t1 (source, target) AS (
SELECT 
t1.study_name,
t1.site_id

FROM  iv_p_mv


UNION ALL


SELECT 
t2.study_name,
t2.site_id
FROM  iv_p_mv as t2 left outer join t1 on t1.study_name = t2.study_name

)

SELECT 
study_name,
site_id
FROM  t1
```

Error:

Reference t1 is not found.

Comment: Please explain what you want to do.  Perhaps you want a recursive CTE.

Comment: @Gordon I’m just looking for a way to fix this query to get some results. Just that issue with t1 as a reference error.

Comment: delete as `FROM  iv_p_mv as t2` so that `FROM  iv_p_mv t2` and try again

Comment: could you pls explain what's the logic behind it? what is your goal here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just out of curiosity. Is this what you need?

```
WITH source AS (
    SELECT t1.study_name, t1.site_id 
    FROM iv_p_mv t1),
    target as (
    SELECT t2.study_name, t2.site_id
    FROM iv_p_mv t2 LEFT OUTER JOIN source s ON s.study_name = t2.study_name
    union all 
    SELECT s.study_name, s.site_id
    FROM source s)   
SELECT
    study_name,
    site_id
FROM target;
```

@KSp *I can see that you accepted this aswer, but if you want a recursive query, it should look more like (see answer and comments from @mathguy)

```
WITH t1 (source, target) AS (
    SELECT study_name   source,
           site_id      target
    FROM iv_p_mv
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t2.study_name,
           t2.site_id
    FROM iv_p_mv t2, t1
    WHERE t1.source = t2.study_name (+)
)
SELECT source, target FROM t1
```

Comment: Very likely not. The OP wrote a recursive query (recursive `WITH` clause). We don't know what the OP really wanted the query to do, but formally there were two (minor) syntax mistakes in his code, otherwise it was a perfectly valid recursive query. From your re-writing of the query, I am willing to bet that you aren't even familiar with the "recursive query" concept. Am I wrong?

Comment: ... as it turns out, closer inspection shows additional errors in the original code, but they are all still related to the "recursive WITH clause" concept. I detailed the additional mistakes in a comment to my own answer (in response to follow-up from the OP).

Comment: @mathguy  just curious ;) ; I understood KSp response above as a plain union all, with query 
^ I’m just looking for a way to fix this query to get some results. Just that issue with t1 as a reference error.
no need to be angry..

Comment: Not sure why you think I am "angry" - that's unsupported speculation on your part. (I am, in fact, not angry at all). So - are you familiar with "recursive WITH clause"? If you say "yes", then I don't understand how you get from the OP's attempt to your code. If you say "no", that's that - no need to discuss further.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the full error message, it should also show you which line of code has the error.

In this case, it would likely point to the fourth line (the same error exists in the third line). In the anchor member of the recursive query (meaning: the first part) you `select t1.study_name, t1.site_id from iv_p_mv`. There is no `t1` in this context - you didn't alias the table (or materialized view) as `t1`. (It would also be a terrible idea to alias it that way - `t1` is the name of the view you are creating in the `WITH` clause, don't also use it somewhere in the `WITH` clause.)

You don't need an alias there - you can simply select `study_name, site_id` in that part of the query.

```
WITH t1 (source, target) AS (
SELECT 
t1.study_name,              -- Remove "t1."
t1.site_id                  -- Remove "t1."

FROM  iv_p_mv


UNION ALL
```

After you fix this, you will find the other error that was already pointed out: in Oracle you can't use the keyword `as` before a table alias (before `t2` in your code). You can use the keyword `as`, optionally, before column aliases, but not before table and view aliases.

Comment: I still get reference t1 not found.

Comment: @KSp - I missed a couple of other mistakes in your code; but if you corrected what I told you, then you shouldn't get an error about "reference t1 not found", unless your code is **not** the one you posted. The additional mistakes are: first, in the `with` clause, you say that the columns will be re-named, from `study_name, site_id` to `source, target`. Not clear why you are doing that, but if you do, you can't reference `t1.study_name`, for example, in the recursive member - that has to be `t1.source`. The other mistake is that the outer join in the recursive WITH clause is not allowed.

Comment: if i put t1.source where i will i be fetching the study_name?

Comment: @KSp - Why are you changing the names from "study_name" and "site_id" to "source" and "target" in the first place? The better "fix" to your code is to change those to "study_name" and "site_id" at the top of the WITH clause - don't use "source" and "target" anywhere. (Or, if that is a requirement, give them as aliases in the final SELECT, after the recursive WITH clause.)